# Is there any plugin in flutter that checks the adjacency of two or more polygons?

Tags: flutter, polygon, fluttermap

I need some logic/plugin in flutter to check if two or more polygons are adjacent to each other or not.

I tried using some default functions and also some plugins like dart_jts, poly_collisions but nothing worked as expected.